# Please help.. Ubuntu 18.04 title bar look stretched

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Ok so I have Surface Pro 3 and I have Ubuntu 18.04 on it because I like it so much 
But I have a problem, the title bar look stretched [image: files]

[image: Settings]

I tried gtk.css, it worked on apps like Firefox but it never worked on settings, ubuntu software, Files ,basically it doesn't work on system apps

But there something quite interesting.
When I open the terminal and type,

```
sudo nautilus
```

It obviously shows the files windows BUT,, when I open the system files
The window becomes normal 
[image: Nautilus]

How to fix this problem??please It's been annoying me for ages